# Solr 8.2 not returning all fields

Tags: solr

I am importing documents from a database using DIH. The loading works fine, but when querying, I am only getting the title field back, no other (first_author in this example) fields.

publication table

```
 publication_id     | int(11)                                
 first_author       | varchar(255)                           
 pubmed_id          | int(10) unsigned                       
 date               | date                                   
 title              | varchar(255)                           
 doi                | varchar(100)                           
 keywords           | varchar(1000)                          
 linked_papers      | varchar(255)                           
 off_target_effects | enum('No','Discussed'...)
 journal_id         | int(11)
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">./db_data_config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" 
            user="root" 
            password=""/>
<document>
  <entity 
    title="publication"  
    name="publication"
    pk="publication_id"
    query="select * from publication"
    >
     <field column="publication_id" title="publication_id"/>
     <field column="title" title="title"/>       
     <field column="first_author" title="first_author"/>       
  </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>\
```

managed_schema (updated via api/webinterface, not directly)

```
<field name="first_author" type="text_en" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title" type="text_en" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Query results

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1564484927531"}},
  "response":{"numFound":160,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "title":"A genome-wide[...]",
        "id":"656e2f96-1a2b-47c7-b6b3-4cd0078b7a30",
        "_version_":1639326538073636864},
 [...]
}}
```

I get this error:

```
SolrWriter
Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [first_author=Moses C,&#8203; title=A genome-wide.,&#8203; id=1d71cfa8-9ced-435d-95c3-cee6c5461ef4,&#8203; _version_=1640489999976628224,&#8203; _root_=1d71cfa8-9ced-435d-95c3-cee6c5461ef4])
```

Comment: is the data index to solr?Did you query the data in solr admin page?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti yes, I did use the admin page for import and query. I don't understand the the first part of your question. Still a newbie with solr.

Comment: @do you see the indexed data when you query through the solr admin page?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti: This the result from the import:
`Requests: 1 1/s, Fetched: 21 11/s, Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0 
Started: less than a minute ago`
_Query result_ in my post show the result from the server. I hope this what you asked.

Comment: *"The loading works fine"*, no this is precisely a loading error.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the log file (after finding hints that it contains more information):

```
 [   ] o.a.s.h.d.SolrWriter Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [first_author=Mohamed HT, title=A genome-wide[...] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id a0c3be47-262a-48d3-8d2d-bb8695470807 to the index; possible analysis error: cannot change field "first_author" from index options=DOCS to inconsistent index options=DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS
```

I changed a field type, and was not aware that I need to re-index. Query worked fine after.

Answer (score 0):

As we see in this line :

```
<field name="first_author" type="text_en" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

You have **uninvertible="true"**

Please notice that tif you set **uninvertible** to **true** it means you need **first_author** to be indexed just to search and find one or multiple documents and use fields which are **invertible**(uninvertible="false"), and you do not need to retrieve **first_author** itself.

The solr documentation says [here](https://solr.pl/en/2018/12/17/solr-7-6-0-uninvertible-fields/) :

> With the recent release of Solr 7.6.0 we got a new option for the
>   fields and field types – the property called uninvertible. It allows
>   us to control what Solr will do when it will require data in an
>   uninverted format, so for example when using faceting or sorting.
>   Let’s look into what happens with various settings of this new
>   property.

Thus if you change it to false you can retrieve first_author.(same for other fields)